# How do I fix 'Invalid arguments: (name) not provided'?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, anchor-lang

I have a withdrawAll function written in Anchor lang but I'm not able to call it, I keep getting

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid arguments: admin not provided."

If you know how I can fix it, please reply!

This is the anchor code:

```
pub fn withdraw_all(ctx: Context<WithdrawAll>, sol_amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let accts = ctx.accounts;

        // withdraw sol
        let bump = ctx.bumps.get("vault").unwrap();
        if sol_amount > 0 {
            invoke_signed(
                &system_instruction::transfer(&accts.vault.key(), &accts.admin.key(), sol_amount),
                &[
                    accts.vault.to_account_info().clone(),
                    accts.admin.to_account_info().clone(),
                    accts.system_program.to_account_info().clone(),
                ],
                &[&[VAULT_SEED, &[*bump]]],
            )?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WithdrawAll<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [GLOBAL_STATE_SEED.as_bytes(), admin.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        constraint = global_state.admin == admin.key()
    )]
    pub global_state: Account<'info, GlobalState>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [VAULT_SEED],
        bump
    )]
    /// CHECK: this should be checked with address in global_state
    pub vault: AccountInfo<'info>,

    // The Token Program
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And this is the way I'm calling this function in JS in my helpers.js file:

```
export const withdrawAll = async (wallet, connection, sol_amount) => {
    const admin1 = new PublicKey("9UvMLuvRrrohJneE8JcQiJ98g3X6iiEE1BKcWSUQD9k2");
    const program = getProgram(wallet, connection);

    const globalStateKey = await getGlobalStateKey(wallet.publicKey);
    const vaultKey = await getVaultKey();

    let globalState = await program.account.globalState.fetch(globalStateKey);

    if (!globalState) {
        showToast("Not initialized", 2000, 1);
        return 0;
    }

    sol_amount = sol_amount * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

    const result = await program.methods.withdrawAll().accounts({
        accounts: {
            admin: admin1,
            globalState: globalStateKey,
            vault: vaultKey,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        }
    }).rpc();

    const amountWithdrawn = result[0];
    console.log(`Withdrawn amount: ${amountWithdrawn / web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL}`);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing the `sol_amount` argument in the instruction.

```
const result = await program.methods.withdrawAll(sol_amount).accounts({
...
```

Also make sure that a `BN` is passed as amount since `sol_amount` arg is of `u64` type.

Also you probably need to define a new variable since you are receiving `sol_amount` as a parameter in the  `withdrawAll` function, you shouldn't redefine that

Comment: Alright thanks but I still get the error:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid arguments: globalState not provided."